# How to Double Click the DataGridView column then it appears in WebView2 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, url, datagridview, webview2, datagridviewcolumn

I want to double click the "Name" column of the datagridview then it appears in webview2 based on the "url" column.

Thanks

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler Me.Resize, AddressOf Form_Resize
        AddHandler WebView.NavigationStarting, AddressOf EnsureHttps
        InitializeAsync()
        Dim t As New DataTable()
        t.Columns.Add("id")
        t.Columns.Add("Name")
        t.Columns.Add("url")
        t.Rows.Add(New Object() {"1", "Philips APAC Centre", "https://www.google.com/search?tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:4&tbm=lcl&q=philips+singapore&rflfq=1&num=10&rldimm=6082032048092871869&ved=2ahUKEwjAuLeM2un-AhWAzzgGHe7qDswQu9QIegQIRhAL#rlfi=hd:;si:3450890534334536328,l,ChFwaGlsaXBzIHNpbmdhcG9yZSIDiAEBSN_D87CqroCACFojEAAYABgBIhFwaGlsaXBzIHNpbmdhcG9yZSoECAIQADICZW6SARZjb25zdW1lcl9hZHZpY2VfY2VudGVyqgFVCgwvZy8xeW16enJzbGQQASoLIgdwaGlsaXBzKAAyHxABIhspDALHL2gj5FH_XQXCrrvZukYbjrVUmSjB-CYyFRACIhFwaGlsaXBzIHNpbmdhcG9yZQ;mv:[[1.4505105,103.89954859999999],[1.2679569,103.79753199999999]]"})
        t.Rows.Add(New Object() {"2", "Philips Lighting (Light Lab)", "https://www.google.com/search?tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:4&tbm=lcl&q=philips+singapore&rflfq=1&num=10&rldimm=6082032048092871869&ved=2ahUKEwjAuLeM2un-AhWAzzgGHe7qDswQu9QIegQIRhAL#rlfi=hd:;si:6082032048092871869,l,ChFwaGlsaXBzIHNpbmdhcG9yZSIDiAEBSL-c_5rngICACFojEAAYABgBIhFwaGlsaXBzIHNpbmdhcG9yZSoECAIQADICZW6SARVsaWdodGluZ19tYW51ZmFjdHVyZXKqAVUKDC9nLzF5bXp6cnNsZBABKgsiB3BoaWxpcHMoADIfEAEiGykMAscvaCPkUf9dBcKuu9m6RhuOtVSZKMH4JjIVEAIiEXBoaWxpcHMgc2luZ2Fwb3Jl;mv:[[1.4505105,103.89954859999999],[1.2679569,103.79753199999999]]"})
        DataGridView1.DataSource = t
        DataGridView1.Columns("url").Visible = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        WebView.Size = Me.ClientSize - New System.Drawing.Size(WebView.Location)
    End Sub
    Private Sub EnsureHttps(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs)
        Dim uri As String = args.Uri
        If Not uri.StartsWith("https://") Then
            WebView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"alert('{url} is not safe, try an https link')")
            args.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Async Sub InitializeAsync()
        Await WebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(Nothing)
        Await WebView.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync("window.chrome.webview.postMessage(window.document.URL);")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really want to click a column, or is it actually a cell you care about? If you care about double-clicking a cell then it seems like there should be something in that code relating to the `CellDoubleClick` event.

Comment: You might also consider using a `DataGridViewLinkColumn` instead of a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`. Clicking a link to open a web page may be more natural than double-clicking text.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Thank you for your feedback. `is it actually a cell you care about?` yes right I want celldoubleclick in the column "Name" then appear in webview2

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `You might also consider using a DataGridViewLinkColumn instead of a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn. Clicking a link to open a web page may be more natural than double-clicking text.` but here I hide that "url" column so can I use DataGridViewLinkColumn?

Comment: A link column simply provides a hyperlink UI. It can display any text you want and the action that is performed when the user clicks the link is completely up to you. You handle the `CellContentClick` event and do whatever is appropriate, so it would just be the same code as you would otherwise put in the `CellDoubleClick` event handler, There's basically no change to the code. It's just the UI that would change. Also, note that you would have to create the link column yourself, as the grid will not do it automatically.

Comment: Basically, handle the appropriate event and check that the column index is correct for the column you want to act you on, then use the row index to get the row and do whatever you want with the data from that row.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , I agree with the recommendations but how do I implement with the code as per your recommendations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to add the columns you want in grid in the designer. Add a text box column for `id` and a link column for `Name`, then set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` in code so no extra columns are generated. Note that you need to set the `DataPropertyName` of each column so it knows how to bind to the data source. You can then handle the `CellContentClick` event of the grid and maths the column index to the index of the link column.

I would also suggest that you add a `BindingSource` in the designer and then bind your `DataTable` via that. You can then get the current record from its `Current` property.

```vb
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
```

and:

```vb
Private Sub myDataGridView_CellContentClick(...) Handles myDataGridView.CellContentClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = linkColumnIndex Then
        Dim url = CStr(DirectCast(myBindingSource.Current, DataRowView)("url"))

        'Use url as desirde.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, first what can DataGridViewLinkColumn which contains url does not appear the contents of the data but with different urls such as "click me" or button and second what can if I hide the column datagridview "url" then I just CellContentClick only in the column "Name"

Comment: @user18, I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry if I made you not understand, So this is how in the datagridview column "url" contains website link data can I change it to "click me" or button but still do not change the data content of the "url" column or can I make the "url" column visible false so that I can click the content of the "name" column still refers to the "url" column

Comment: @user18, I thought the point was to display the name as a link and, when that was clicked, open the URL. I've explained how to do that. If you want to display something else as a link then by all means add another column. The principle is still the same regardless: handle the appropriate event, confirm the column, get the appropriate data from the same row and then use it as desired.

Comment: If the "URL" field is hidden, can it be applied to adding columns as you said?

Comment: Thank you your code went perfectly and after I learned I just set the index column as I wanted and even though the "url" column was hidden

Comment: @user18, if you did what I actually told you to do then there is not URL column to hide. If you're not showing a column in the grid then it doesn't need to be there at all. My answer demonstrates how to get the URL data from the data source, which is what you should be doing.